# How to pass string into react-router-dom Route as function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using React 16.11.0 and react-router-dom 5.1.2.

I have an array of objects representing pages like this:

```
const pages = [{ url: "/", component: "Home" }, {...}, ... ]
```

Update: Maybe I should mention this is from a JSON string so I don't get to determine the type of the values.

I want to dynamically generate Routes in React by mapping over it:

```
import Home from './components/Home';
...
<BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        {pages.map(page => (
            <Route path={page.url} component={page.component} />
        ))}
      </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

`page.url` works but URLs can be strings anyway. `page.component` is not loading properly, I think because it is a string whereas the imported `Home` is a React function component.

I've tried to use `eval()` and `Function()` to convert the `page.component` string into objects but they don't work.

I've tried the docs and search engines but haven't been able to figure out a solution. Maybe I'm searching in the wrong places.

Is this possible? How should I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can even avoid importing modules - `require` comes handy:

```
const pages = [{ url: "/", component: "Home" }, {...}, ...]
   .map((obj) => (
      { url: obj.url, component: require(`./components/${obj.component}`).default }
   );
```

And then following your logic:

```
<Switch>
   {pages.map(page => (
      <Route path={page.url} component={page.component} />
   ))}
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting page.component to Home.

Instead of this:

```
const pages = [{ url: "/", component: "Home" }, {...}, ... ]
```

Try this:

```
const pages = [{ url: "/", component: Home }, {...}, ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the solution the only part you need is to create components dynamically, so

```
const pages = [
   { url: "/", component: Home },
   { url: "/about", component: About }
 ];
```

Keep in mind components should be defined before such as Home, About etc.